# Как можно вытянуть из Facebook и Google+ имя пользователя и Email?

Tags: java, android

При разработке столкнулся с проблемой. Она заключается в том, что нужно пройти авторизацию через вышеуказанные соц сети, и вытянуть опять же вышеуказанные данные, для отправки на сервер. Как это можно реализовать? Может есть какие-либо библиотеки? Не знаю даже с какой стороны подступиться. 
Прошу не судить строго, так как новичок в этом деле.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала скопипастить код из документации, скомпилировать и запустить. Многое станет яснее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых скачайте [facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/), далее нужно прочитать [документацию](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/), она на русском языке, так что проблем не возникнет :), и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196682/facebook-android-sdk-4-5-0-get-email-address) пример как получить email, на счет имени пользователя есть пример в документации.
Google+ думаю примерно также, с ней не работал, так что утверждать не буду.
[Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

Comment: Спасибо, выручили

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайтесь.